# what is the standard key to open context menu in internet explore

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer, keyword

i am trying to open context menu in internet explore browser using key SHIFT+F10 but it will not open 
.In chrome browser it will work proper but in internet explore not.any keys for open context menu in internet explore 
In my laptop keyboard menu key with Ctrl that i had also try , but it not working

Comment: There's literally a key on your keyboard called the [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) just for that.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i had try these keys but it not working

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard already Provide that kind of key that emulate mouse right click for open context menu.

Key icon is look like below :

[image]

Comment: hi  mayur,  in my laptop keyboard the menu key with ctr i had try but this not working

Comment: Thanks For reply, I thought that It may be helpful, so I wrote that. But I don''t know any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Jyoti**

Besides having an specific key on the keyboard to pull this context menu, the standard shortcut for all browsers is indeed what you are mentioning on your post as you can see in this **[list of shortcuts for all internet browsers](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm)**.

The context menu key, if your keyboard has it, is often located on the bottom right side next to your Windows menu key. A lot of times, though, that menu key either isn't there or isn't easily accessible, and when that's the case, **Shift-F10** is there for you.

[image: The context menu key location]

I certainly hope this answers your question, buddy!

Comment: @Aivison Hunter i had try this one but its not working

Comment: I totally believe you, I am not sure if is something related to the version, I would dare to believe it is like so. I am sending you a list of shortcuts available for IExplorer 8 and up for your reference into what's possible and what is not in this browser.

http://www.shortcutmania.com/Internet-Explorer-8-Keyboard-Shortcuts-printable-cheatsheet.htm

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE browser are you using? I have checked the shortcut key **Shift+F10** and the [keyboard menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key), they all work well on Window 10 OS and IE 11 browser.

Besides, you could also try to use **Ctrl+Shift+F10** shortcut key.